# how to change some integer result to string in datatables codeigniter

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, datatables

i have an apps with codeigniter as framework and ignited datatables as table libraries and also serverside. i would like to generate the table, and i put the code in the codeigniter controller, example :

```
$this->datatables->select('name,address,gender')
->from('person');

echo $this->datatables->generate();
```

in the database table, the value of gender column just integer, with 1 and 2 as value, i mean 1 as male, and 2 as female. how to setting if the value detect 1 the view is male and if 2 the view is female in the table ?

Answer (score 1):

```
$person = $this->datatables->select('name,address,gender')
->from('person');
if($person->gender == 1)
{
// do what happens when male
}
else if($person->gender == 2)
{
// do what happens when female
}
```